# Percolation code in Java keeps throwing IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java

I am working on visualizing a Percolation in Java. I have the following code for the Percolation Visualizer: PercolationVisualizer.java

```
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.In;
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.StdDraw;

import java.awt.Font;

public class PercolationVisualizer {

// delay in milliseconds (controls animation speed)
private static final int DELAY = 100;

// draw n-by-n percolation system
public static void draw(Percolation percolation, int n) {
StdDraw.clear();
StdDraw.setPenColor(StdDraw.BLACK);
StdDraw.setXscale(-0.05 * n, 1.05 * n);
StdDraw.setYscale(-0.05 * n, 1.05 * n); // leave a 5% border
StdDraw.filledSquare(n / 2.0, n / 2.0, n / 2.0);

// draw n-by-n grid
for (int row = 0; row < n; row++) {
for (int col = 0; col < n; col++) {
if (percolation.isFull(row, col)) {
StdDraw.setPenColor(StdDraw.BOOK_LIGHT_BLUE);
}
else if (percolation.isOpen(row, col)) {
StdDraw.setPenColor(StdDraw.WHITE);
}
else {
StdDraw.setPenColor(StdDraw.BLACK);
}
StdDraw.filledSquare(col + 0.5, n - row - 0.5, 0.45);
}
}

// write status text
StdDraw.setFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.PLAIN, 12));
StdDraw.setPenColor(StdDraw.BLACK);
StdDraw.text(0.25 * n, -0.025 * n, percolation.numberOfOpenSites() + " open sites");
if (percolation.percolates()) StdDraw.text(0.75 * n, -0.025 * n, "percolates");
else StdDraw.text(0.75 * n, -0.025 * n, "does not percolate");

}

private static void simulateFromFile(String filename) {
In in = new In(filename);
int n = in.readInt();
Percolation percolation = new Percolation(n);

// turn on animation mode
StdDraw.enableDoubleBuffering();

// repeatedly read in sites to open and draw resulting system
draw(percolation, n);
StdDraw.show();
StdDraw.pause(DELAY);

while (!in.isEmpty()) {
int row = in.readInt();
int col = in.readInt();
percolation.open(row, col);
draw(percolation, n);
StdDraw.show();
StdDraw.pause(DELAY);
}
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
String filename = args[0];
simulateFromFile(filename);
}
}
```

And I am testing it with the following input file: input20.txt

```
20
6 10
17 10
11 4
8 4
4 8
0 0
11 0
4 3
15 18
2 12
8 13
11 3
3 10
2 2
1 1
4 16
4 19
16 10
9 2
3 16
12 3
3 17
2 3
7 14
12 4
14 6
18 19
18 17
4 0
18 10
8 9
6 14
6 0
8 12
2 11
1 12
3 9
9 10
8 0
9 16
12 14
8 5
5 4
7 16
5 8
13 5
4 9
3 11
11 15
17 1
4 10
14 15
16 12
3 14
10 2
10 12
17 19
7 11
4 5
1 5
13 17
12 13
10 6
10 19
10 13
12 9
14 16
5 14
17 9
13 10
2 0
7 9
11 13
5 13
13 9
10 8
8 18
14 1
18 5
14 12
5 1
7 6
8 8
9 6
13 19
13 7
0 13
10 14
18 0
17 7
12 7
17 11
1 4
4 1
3 6
3 19
13 12
1 7
14 11
19 11
11 6
7 13
4 4
17 15
4 11
9 14
1 6
4 18
2 8
19 12
10 7
15 17
3 4
8 14
16 9
13 18
18 7
6 12
18 11
10 11
14 17
12 17
13 0
10 18
11 18
16 3
11 5
0 8
3 8
17 8
16 18
12 19
6 1
1 3
7 10
18 6
11 1
19 5
3 15
14 4
14 2
16 5
16 11
0 4
4 13
19 6
17 6
2 18
13 14
15 16
16 14
18 18
9 5
0 7
1 8
14 10
5 6
11 17
14 3
17 16
0 10
15 19
15 3
18 8
0 6
7 1
0 12
18 12
7 2
15 2
3 1
14 8
10 3
3 0
0 14
3 7
7 12
13 11
18 13
17 14
4 6
16 13
3 5
6 8
12 6
1 14
10 0
15 10
17 4
10 1
14 14
14 7
16 6
15 7
17 0
17 2
2 17
6 7
9 13
13 13
16 15
0 3
17 12
6 9
15 1
5 7
10 5
11 8
11 10
6 5
1 2
12 0
0 1
14 0
12 15
16 19
12 18
14 18
7 0
18 9
4 12
0 16
13 4
5 9
11 11
6 15
19 18
8 10
2 5
15 0
19 0
6 17
19 4
6 11
8 1
7 19
2 14
2 13
2 4
4 17
18 16
15 11
19 3
4 15
5 2
7 5
11 14
1 15
15 5
0 17
```

This is my Percolation file: Percolation.java that I need to run the visualizer.

```
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.StdOut;
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.WeightedQuickUnionUF;

public class Percolation {
private boolean[][] grid; // grid
private WeightedQuickUnionUF wqfGrid; // quick union for grid
private WeightedQuickUnionUF wqfFull; // quick union for full
private int gridSize; // grid size
private int virtualTop; // top virtual site
private int virtualBottom; // bottom virtual site
private int openSites; // number of open sites

// creates n-by-n grid, with all sites initially blocked
public Percolation(int n) {
if (n <= 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
gridSize = n;
grid = new boolean[gridSize][gridSize];
wqfGrid = new WeightedQuickUnionUF(n * n + 2);
wqfFull = new WeightedQuickUnionUF(n * n + 1);
virtualBottom = n * n + 1;
virtualTop = n * n;
openSites = 0;
}

// opens the site (row, col) if it is not open already
public void open(int row, int col) {
validateSite(row, col);

int shiftRow = row - 1;
int shiftCol = col - 1;
int flatIndex = flattenGrid(row, col) - 1;

// if site is already open, stop
if (isOpen(row, col)) {
return;
}

// open site
grid[shiftRow][shiftCol] = true;
openSites++;

if (row == 1) { // top row
wqfGrid.union(virtualTop, flatIndex);
wqfFull.union(virtualTop, flatIndex);
}

if (row == gridSize) { // bottom row
wqfGrid.union(virtualBottom, flatIndex);
}

// check and open site on left
if (isOnGrid(row, col - 1) && isOpen(row, col - 1)) {
wqfGrid.union(flatIndex, flattenGrid(row, col - 1) - 1);
wqfFull.union(flatIndex, flattenGrid(row, col - 1) - 1);
}

// check and open site on right
if (isOnGrid(row, col + 1) && isOpen(row, col + 1)) {
wqfGrid.union(flatIndex, flattenGrid(row, col + 1) - 1);
wqfFull.union(flatIndex, flattenGrid(row, col + 1) - 1);
}

// check and open site on top (up)
if (isOnGrid(row - 1, col) && isOpen(row - 1, col)) {
wqfGrid.union(flatIndex, flattenGrid(row - 1, col) - 1);
wqfFull.union(flatIndex, flattenGrid(row - 1, col) - 1);
}

// check and open site on bottom (down)
if (isOnGrid(row + 1, col) && isOpen(row + 1, col)) {
wqfGrid.union(flatIndex, flattenGrid(row + 1, col) - 1);
wqfFull.union(flatIndex, flattenGrid(row + 1, col) - 1);
}
}

// is the site (row, col) open?
public boolean isOpen(int row, int col) {
validateSite(row, col);
return grid[row - 1][col - 1];

}

// is the site (row, col) full?
public boolean isFull(int row, int col) {
validateSite(row, col);
return wqfFull.find(virtualTop) == wqfFull.find(flattenGrid(row, col) - 1);
}

// returns the number of open sites
public int numberOfOpenSites() {
return openSites;
}

// does the system percolate?
public boolean percolates() {
return wqfGrid.find(virtualTop) == wqfGrid.find(virtualBottom);
}

// unit testing (required)
public static void main(String[] args) {
int size = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

Percolation percolation = new Percolation(size);
int argCount = args.length;
for (int i = 1; argCount >= 2; i += 2) {
int row = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
int col = Integer.parseInt(args[i + 1]);
StdOut.printf("Adding row: %d col: %d %n", row, col);
percolation.open(row, col);
if (percolation.percolates()) {
StdOut.printf("%nThe System percolates %n");
}
argCount -= 2;
}
if (!percolation.percolates()) {
StdOut.print("Does not percolate %n");
}

}

// flatten grid
private int flattenGrid(int row, int col) {
return gridSize * (row - 1) + col;
}

// check site
private void validateSite(int row, int col) {
if (!isOnGrid(row, col)) {
throw new IllegalArgumentException();
}
}

private boolean isOnGrid(int row, int col) {
int shiftRow = row - 1;
int shiftCol = col - 1;
return (shiftRow >= 0 && shiftCol >= 0 && shiftRow < gridSize && shiftCol < gridSize);
}
}
}
}
```

When I run java-algs4 PercolationVisualizer input20.txt, I receive the following error messages:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
at Percolation.validateSite(Percolation.java:129)
at Percolation.isFull(Percolation.java:85)
at PercolationVisualizer.draw(PercolationVisualizer.java:40)
at PercolationVisualizer.simulateFromFile(PercolationVisualizer.java:71)
at PercolationVisualizer.main(PercolationVisualizer.java:87)
```

**So, How can I fix this to make it work?** Also, how can I make sure that all methods are called in main()? **Also, any suggestions on ways to improve the code and/or make it clearer and more concise?**

Comment: The error happens in your `isOnGrid` check. What happens when the site is at (0,0)?

Comment: " Also, any suggestions on ways to improve the code and/or make it clearer" Use indentation. It is currently near-impossible to see the code's structure.

Comment: @CatMai how do you recommend fixing this?

Comment: Not sure why you need the shift -1, so I'd recommend deleting that. Also echoing @AndyTurner, please edit with indentation or use it next time.